# Memory leak in Google App Engine / Datastore / Flask / Python app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-datastore

I have built a simple news aggregator site, in which the memory usage of all my App Engine instances keep growing until reaching the limit and therefore being shut down.

I have started to eliminate everything from my app to arrive at a minimal reproducible version. This is what I have now:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

datastore_client = datastore.Client()

@app.route('/')
def root():
    
    query = datastore_client.query(kind='source')
    query.order = ['list_sequence']
    sources = query.fetch() 
    
    for source in sources:
        pass
```

Stats show a typical saw-tooth pattern: at instance startup, it goes to 190 - 210 Mb, then upon some requests, but NOT ALL requests, memory usage increases by 20 - 30 Mb. (This, by the way, roughly corresponds to the estimated size of the query results, although I cannot be sure this is relevant info.) This keeps happening until it exceeds 512 Mb, when it is shut down. It usually happens at around the 50th - 100th request to "/". No other requests are made to anything else in the meantime.

Now, if I eliminate the "for" cycle, and only the query remains, the problem goes away, the memory usage remains at 190 Mb flat, no increase even after 100+ requests.

gc.collect() at the end does not help. I have also tried looking at the difference in tracemalloc stats at the beginning and end of the function, I have not found anything useful.

Has anyone experienced anything similar, please? Any ideas what might go wrong here? What additional tests / investigations can you recommend? Is this possibly a Google App Engine / Datastore issue I have no control of?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alex in the other answer did a pretty good research, so I will follow up with this recommendation: try using the [NDB Library](https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb). All calls with this library have to be wrapped into a context manager, which should guarantee cleaning up after closing. That could help fix your problem:

```
ndb_client = ndb.Client(**init_client)

with ndb_client.context():
    query = MyModel.query().order(MyModel.my_column)
    sources = query.fetch()
    for source in sources:
        pass

# if you try to query DataStore outside the context manager, it will raise an error
query = MyModel.query().order(MyModel.my_column)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and report back. But, isn't this library up for deprecation? This is what I have found on Google's app engine pages when I started this project: "New Python 3 apps should use the Datastore mode client library instead of Cloud NDB."

Comment: Status: In progress of implementing this. The difficulty is that my site is live and I have trouble querying entities with ndb, originally created by datastore. Specifically, i have an "array" field in a datastore entity into which I stored a list of dicts. When trying to iterate the query in ndb, I get an error on this, "Lists cannot be wrapped.". I am still trying to figure this one out.

Comment: Result: I have completely rewritten my app to use ndb, as instructed by yedpodtrzitko above. The problem is basically gone. (There is still a very low continuous increase of the memory usage, but it makes the issue negligible to me.) Plus, my response times are noticeable faster, plus, the app is now able to run on a lower instance class, at least halving my daily cost. So this is a success, thank you for your help. Of course, the original problem with the datastore api is still there, I have raised an issue on github.

Comment: glad to hear this helped

Comment: ￼Unfortunately I have declared success prematurely. The memory leak related instance shutdowns still happen, even with ndb, although more infrequently. It is not a disaster for me, but I thought I mention this for the sake of the full picture. The bottom line is, I still have no understanding of the root cause. (See current memory usage chart above - where it drops to zero, that's where there is an instance shutdown.)

Comment: oh noo, sorry to hear that.

Comment: Hey @KaaRoy,
I am facing the same problem, the comments look 2 years old. Let me know if you have figured out a solution.
Also, thanks for the discussion it helped.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never managed to resolve this problem, I am living with it. I have made no further attempt in the last year.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, if I eliminate the "for" cycle, and only the query remains, the problem goes away, the memory usage remains at 190 Mb flat, no increase even after 100+ requests.

`query.fetch()` returns an iterator, not an actual array of the results

https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/queries.html#google.cloud.datastore.query.Query.fetch

Looking at the source code, it looks like this iterator has code for fetching the next pages of the query. So you're for-loop forces it to fetch all the pages of the results. In fact I don't think it actually fetches anything until you start iterating. So that would be why removing your for-loop would make a difference

Unfortunately beyond that I'm not sure, since as you dig through the source code you pretty quickly run into the GRPC stubs and it's unclear if the problem is in there.

There is this question that is similar to yours, where the asker found a memory leak involved with instantiating `datastore.Client()`.
[How should I investigate a memory leak when using Google Cloud Datastore Python libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396879/how-should-i-investigate-a-memory-leak-when-using-google-cloud-datastore-python)

This ultimately got linked to an issue in GRPC where GRPC would leak if it doesn't get closed
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22123

Hopefully, this points you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you. These seem to be relevant conversations you have pointed at, a little bit beyond my current comprehension though. The only actual recommendation, to set GOOGLE_CLOUD_DISABLE_GRPC, I have tried, unfortunately without impact. I am searching on.